# B2 VISA REJECTION DILEMMA

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, us-visa-waiver-program, australian-citizens

Both my wife and I applied recently for a B2 visa. The purpose is to stay longer period than what ESTA offers (90 days). We're Australian Citizens, in the early 60s, both have full time job with strong ties to our home country Australia. The B2 Visa interview is arranged on Mid June 2019, however currently my wife has a valid ESTA visa waiver and this is valid up-to October 2020 to travel USA. To be on the safer-side and not caught up with any B2 Visa rejection, I am thinking to postpone the B2 visa interview to a future date for both of us and me applying a  ESTA visa waiver given any rejection in B2 Visa will trigger cancellation of ESTA visa. By postponing the B2 Visa interview, at least we can visit USA to see few tourist places and see our grandchild, friends and relatives. Once returned from USA we can then attend the B2 Visa interview say middle of 2020. Our understanding is B2 Visa interview can be re-arranged within 365 days of form submission. Could anyone kindly assist by postponing the B2 visa interview to a future date is more appropriate in our situation and better option to making the visit to USA in August 2019 using ESTA? In this way, we are not breaking any rules and not getting stranded at the US port of entry.

Comment: Your dilemma is whether to postpone the B2 interview until after you've visited your family in the US. The answer is entirely opinion-based, as it's dependent upon how you and your wife value seeing your family earlier, but for a more limited time, compared to delaying the visit perhaps to stay longer. That's a matter of opinion, and we try to not do opinion here. Thus, I voted to close as primarily opinion-based. Perhaps you can rewrite the question (use the "edit" button under the question text) so it meets the guidelines: see https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning, here. If you're worried that your B2 will be rejected, you should be equally worried that you'll be refused entry under the VWP for what sounds like a shorter version of the same trip.